# can i use reverse relationship with OneToOneField

Tags: python, django

```
class EmailActivaion(models.Model):
user =     models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

could i make the following code:

```
qs=User.objects.filter(email='bla@bla.com')
obj=qs.first()
em = obj.EmailActivaion_set.all()
```

as I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'EmailActivaion_set'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you use a `OneToOneField`, it means that the *target model* (here `User`) has *at most* one `EmailActivation` object attached to it.

So as a result, the reverse relation is not `somemodel_set`, but simply `somemodel`.

So you should write:

```
# fetches the single EmailActivation instance,
# or raises an EmailActivation.DoesNotExist error (in case no exists)
em = obj.emailactivation
```

This will *directly* fetch the object that is related to the `User` instance `obj`.

> **Note**: It is possible that *no* `EmailActivation` instance is associated with this `User`, in that case it will raise a `EmailActivation.DoesNotExist` error, so perhaps you want to write `try`-`except` logic around this.

> **Note** I fixed a spelling error: it is `EmailActivation` (with two `t`s)

> **Note**: the name of the relation is the name of the model **in lowercase**, so not <s>`obj.EmailActivation`</s>, but `obj.emailactivation`.

> **Note**: typically it is better to refer to the **`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** instead of to the `User` model directly: if you later change the user model to a custom model, then you do not have to rewrite all those models. By default `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is `User`, but you can later set it to a different model.

Comment: Thank you Willem very much for the fast and comprehensive response